# Does a successful exit of rsync -acvvv s d guarantee identical directory trees?

Tags: linux, command-line, sync, rsync, gnu

I have two volumes, one xfs, and another ntfs - ntfs was empty, and xfs had 10 subitems.

I needed to sync them.
I initially copied a few of the subitems by dragging them over in a gui fm. Several of the direct descendants which i had dragged finished, apparently. One I stopped before it was done, and the rest I cancelled while it still appeared to be gathering information about the files.

Then I ran `rsync -acvvv xmp/ nmp/`, where `xmp` and `nmp` are the volumes' respective mountpoints, which exited with a 0 status.
`find xmp -printf x | wc -c` and `find nmp -printf x | wc -c` both return 372926.

My question is: Am I guaranteed that the two drives' contents are identical?

Answer (score 0):

**TLNR:** Given the fact that you have the same amount of files & dirs in both (source & dest) after a successful rsync, yes they are identical.

An exit status of 0 will in this case mean that all the content of xmp/ is entirely in nmp/. But no the other way arround. It's an unidirectional process.

To be strictly *identical* using rsync you also need to delete all possible content of nmp/ which is not present in xmp/ (called extraneous files in rsync manual) using the **--delete** parameter.